# Calling jquery function with function(e) parameters from another jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        $("#submitButton").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!$('#formValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()) 
                $('#formValidator').bootstrapValidator('validate');
            if  (!$('#jobValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid())
                $('#jobValidator').bootstrapValidator('validate');

            if(($('#formValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()) & ($('#jobValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()))
            {
                var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%=saveButton.ClientID %>");
                clickButton.click();
            }
        });

        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {

                $("#submitButton").click();
            }
        });
```

I want  `$(document).keypress(function(e)` which captures enter key on the page to call `$(document).keypress(function(e)` which validates my form and call my code behind.

Both of my functions work on their own, I just dont know how to call my button click function from enter key function. Probably because I have to pass `(function(e)` and I havent been able to figure out how.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than pass anonymous functions, you can save a reference to a function in a variable, and pass that reference to jQuery. For example:

```
var validateFunc = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$('#formValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()) 
        $('#formValidator').bootstrapValidator('validate');
    if  (!$('#jobValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid())
        $('#jobValidator').bootstrapValidator('validate');

    if(($('#formValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()) & ($('#jobValidator').data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()))
    {
        var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%=saveButton.ClientID %>");
        clickButton.click();
    }
};

$("#submitButton").click(validateFunc);

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        validateFunc(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to trigger click event

```
$( "#submitButton" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: It is same as `$("#submitButton").click();`, simply using `.click()` is equivalent to trigger.